# How to style optgroup labels and options?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the optgroup labels and options. Here's my HTML:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option>Option 1.1</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option>Option 2.1</option>
    <option>Option 2.2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 3" disabled>
    <option>Option 3.1</option>
    <option>Option 3.2</option>
    <option>Option 3.3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fpfLbcmb/

Specifically, I'd like to make the labels not bold and the options not indented. However, my CSS below doesn't change the appearance as expected.

```
optgroup {
    font-weight: normal;
}
option {
    margin: 0;
}
```

How can I make the labels non-bold and remove the indent on the options?

Comment: Have you tried adding a css class? `<optgroup label="Group 1" class="mygroup">` and then css `.mygroup {font-weight:normal;} `

Comment: Just tried it (see https://jsfiddle.net/fpfLbcmb/2/) but no luck.

Comment: I just opened your second fiddle link, and for me it is working. Maybe it's a caching issue in your browser? Try refreshing the page with ctrl+F5 (or cmd+f5 on a mac), and see what happens.

Comment: @Tijmen which browser are you using? I'm using Chrome

Comment: I'm using Firefox on Linux. EDIT: I've just tried it in Chrome, and interestingly enough it doesn't seem to work there. Chrome apparently feels a `bolder` look is 'normal' of optgroups. Changing `normal` to a value like `200` does make a difference.

Comment: Thanks @Tijmen, that's very helpful!